# How to install older version of GhostScript?

Tags: 11.04, installation, ghostscript

This is [second time](https://askubuntu.com/questions/61407/segmentation-fault-error-ghostscript) I get segmentation fault error when I try to run GhostScript on any PDF file with pdfwrite
First time it was my previous Ubuntu 11.04 distro, which afterwards I completely remove (not because of gs), format my drive etc, and then install 11.04 again

I don't know what could be the problem. I work with GS a lot, and now all of a sudden I start getting this errors on any file, like something went wrong with this package or some of it's dependencies.
I searched Synaptic history if there maybe some recent update could cause GS crippling but there was nothing

I reported problems in the past (at least two times) on GS Launchpad branch, but no one even replied, and as a matter of fact no one ever replied to me on Launchpad for any report I issue, so I thought to remove completely ghostscript and install some other version.
At first I thought to add Debian stable repository, and install better tested version, but it turned out that perhaps that's not very good idea - adding Debian repository in Ubuntu.

As I can't "force" Synaptic to some previous GS version (as there is only one it seems - problematic one) I don't know how to approach this problem and wanted to ask how to install previous version, 8.71 preferably, because that's the last version in Debian stable.

---

**Update:**

I removed GS 9.01 (and bunch of other packages on the way) and followed Boris' advice, as I didn't know what else can I do.

I installed:

```
libgs8_8.71~dfsg2-9_i386.deb
ghostscript_8.71~dfsg2-9_i386.deb
```

and tested GS interpreter and all was working fine.

Now I wanted to put back all those packages removed by GS 9.01 removal, and I needed to first install `ghostscript-x`:

```
ghostscript-x_8.71~dfsg2-9_i386.deb
```

This is where problem begins:

> Error:
>   Breaks existing package 'gsfonts' that conflict: 'gs'.
>   But the '/home/zetah/gs/ghostscript-x_8.71~dfsg2-9_i386.deb' provides it via: 'gs,gs-afpl,gs-esp,gs-gpl'

I didn't want to brake things so I removed just installed `libgs8` and `ghostscript` and tried to remove `gsfonts` package (which additionally removed abiword, gnumeric,..) and then install all again.
But I found out that `gsfonts` is required by `ghostscript` and installed whenever `ghostscript` is installed (so ever before being able to install `ghostscript-x` package).

Now after installing `libgs8` and `ghostscript`, when I try to install `ghostscript-x` I get:

> Error:
>   Breaks existing package 'ghostscript' that conflict: 'gs'.
>   But the '/home/zetah/gs/ghostscript-x_8.71~dfsg2-9_i386.deb' provides it via: 'gs,gs-afpl,gs-esp,gs-gpl'

It's exactly the same if I try with Ubuntu 10.10 ghostscript 8.71 packages from Launchpad

Comment: Have you tried simply downloading the GhostScript package from debian repository, and installing with dpkg? It is at ftp://ftp.debian.org/debian/pool/main/g/ghostscript There might be a better way.

Comment: I thought of it, but wouldn't that mess with some Ubuntu packages as there are many packages depending on GS, libgs etc?

Comment: Possibly. But it might better than being stuck with a broken package. Unless things go horribly wrong, you should be able to go back. Hopefully, someone more knowledgeable than myself will come along, and answer your question.

Answer (score 5):

As an alternative solution - you could compile the older version of ghostscript.

**download and extract the tar file**

[Download](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+archive/primary/+files/ghostscript_8.71.dfsg.2.orig.tar.gz) the tar file from launchpad.

**setup the build environment**

```
sudo apt-get build-dep ghostscript-x
```

**compile and install ghostscript**

```
cd [ghostscript folder location]
sh autogen.sh
make
sudo make install
```

**binaries**

All the binaries are installed in `/usr/local/bin`

Thus if you run `gs -v`:

> GPL Ghostscript 8.71 (2010-02-10) Copyright (C) 2010 Artifex
>   Software, Inc.  All rights reserved.

If you want to run `ghostscript` you can reassign the current symbolic link:

```
sudo rm /usr/bin/ghostscript
sudo ln -s /usr/local/bin/gs /usr/bin/ghostscript
```

Comment: I didn't try this, but I expect it to work as explained. Seems like a working alternative in similar scenarios not just ghostscript.

Answer (score 3):

Here is solution tried & tested on Ubuntu 12.04 LTS....

Download sources from http://downloads.ghostscript.com/public/

```
wget http://downloads.ghostscript.com/public/ghostscript-8.71.tar.gz
```

Uncompress downloaded source code & change to directory.

```
tar xvf ghostscript-8.71.tar.gz
cd ghostscript-8.71
```

Configure it (I used all defaults)

```
./configure
```

Start compilation with

```
make
```

If you encounter following error:

> ./base/gp_unix.c:148:2: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘gettimeofday’ [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
>   make: *** [obj/gp_unix.o] Error 1

Compile using

```
make XCFLAGS=-DHAVE_SYS_TIME_H=1
```

Finally install compiled binaries using

```
make install
```

At this point you will ghostscript will be installed at `/usr/local/bin/gs`

Comment: The answer above mine answer has remaining parts. Is it fine to copy major part from it OR from the link I posted?

Comment: Your answer should standalone without people having to click on the link to know what to do. If you are referring from other sources, please reference it properly.

Comment: Please check now. Posted everything here. Removed link as its no longer needed. Exception - if I discover any issue with my ghostscript compilation, I will have to edit stuff at 2 places! ;-)

Comment: @jokerdino my pleasure :-)

Answer (score 2):

I also asked this question on Debian forums: [link](http://forums.debian.net/viewtopic.php?f=10&t=73408), and with the help by member **damgaard** I've been able to downgrade GhostScript without too much trouble

Here is overview of this more general scheme which I believe can be used in similar situation, compiled from damgaard's posts:

After removing offending package (GS 9.01) search for last Ubuntu version supporting desired package (GS 8.71) - that is Ubuntu 10.10, so it's repositories are added to helper file: `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/maverick.list`

Investigating which packages are affected by this downgrade idea, we can get this list:

> ghostscript ghostscript-cups ghostscript-doc ghostscript-x libgs8
>   evince evince-common libevdocument3 libevview3 libspectre1

on which we run this one-liner (as sudo):

```
for a in ghostscript ghostscript-cups ghostscript-doc ghostscript-x libgs8 evince evince-common libevdocument3 libevview3 libspectre1; do echo -e "Package: $a\nPin: release a=maverick\nPin-Priority: 700" > /etc/apt/preferences.d/ps_downgrade_policies_$a; done
```

which creates following files in `/etc/apt/preferences.d/` folder:

> ps_downgrade_policies_evince
>   ps_downgrade_policies_evince-common
>   ps_downgrade_policies_ghostscript
>   ps_downgrade_policies_ghostscript-cups
>   ps_downgrade_policies_ghostscript-doc
>   ps_downgrade_policies_ghostscript-x
>   ps_downgrade_policies_libevdocument3
>   ps_downgrade_policies_libevview3
>   ps_downgrade_policies_libgs8
>   ps_downgrade_policies_libspectre1

with this example content:

> Package: package-name-here
>   Pin: release a=maverick
>   Pin-Priority: 1000

Then run:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

Thanks damgaard :)

Answer (score 1):

Try installing a newer version instead: https://launchpad.net/~dns/+archive/gnu

Comment: This is good idea, only that I already solved this problem. I used that PPA to update `gnumeric` (latest version has conditional formatting) and missed to search for solution to my `ghostscript` problem. Too late...